# Efficient vectorization on dates

Tags: r

Basicly I've got a function that I'll need to run close to 1M times and is taking a lot of time because it is not vectorized (my guess)

The idea is that there's a parameter `pf.d.day` that contains a date, and the output will be a transformation of that date (adding/removing days)

`pf.s.Freq` will offset the date to the next period.

08 Apr 2020 with Freq = "month" will become 01 May 2020

08 Apr 2020 with Freq = "week"  will become 13 Apr 2020 #week starts on monday

08 Apr 2020 with Freq = "year"  will become 01 Jan 2021

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
fn.Delay <- function(pf.d.day, pf.s.Freq){
    d.DateWithouthDelay <- as.Date(
        #note: using chained ifs instead of parsing pf.s.Freq into unit to avoid errors from misspells on excel file
        ifelse(pf.s.Freq == "day",     as.character(ceiling_date(pf.d.day + days(1), unit = "day"    )),
        ifelse(pf.s.Freq == "week",    as.character(ceiling_date(pf.d.day + days(1), unit = "week", week_start = 1)),
        ifelse(pf.s.Freq == "month",   as.character(ceiling_date(pf.d.day + days(1), unit = "month"  )),
        ifelse(pf.s.Freq == "quarter", as.character(ceiling_date(pf.d.day + days(1), unit = "quarter")),
        ifelse(pf.s.Freq == "year",    as.character(ceiling_date(pf.d.day + days(1), unit = "year"   )),
        ifelse(pf.s.Freq != "BiWeek", "1900-1-2", #default date if pf.s.Freq is wrong
            ifelse( day(pf.d.day) < 15, 
                as.character(pf.d.day - day(pf.d.day) +15),
                as.character(ceiling_date(pf.d.day, unit = "month")))
        )))))))
    return(d.DateWithouthDelay)
}
```

for a small example:

```
data.frame(
        Di = as.Date(c("2020-4-8", "2020-4-8", "2020-4-8", "2020-4-8", "2020-4-8", "2020-4-8", "2020-4-8")),
        Fr = c("day", "week", "month", "quarter", "year", "BiWeek", "ups")) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(Df = fn.Delay(Di, Fr)) %>%
    data.frame()
```

The main problem with this code is it's speed. Mainly because it's not vectorized but probably also because I'm having to constantly change between dates and characters simply because `ifelse` likes to mess the dates

Comment: Why `rowwise`? Swapping out `ifelse` for `dplyr::case_when` - since you're already using `dplyr` - should help a bit. But your function does look vectorized...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is vectorized. Remove the `rowwise` for a speed increase and the same result:

```
identical(
  dd %>% mutate(Df = fn.Delay(Di, Fr)) %>% pull(Df),
  dd %>%rowwise() %>% mutate(Df = fn.Delay(Di, Fr)) %>% pull(Df)
)
# TRUE
```

`ifelse` isn't actually that bad. Here's a simplified version using `case_when`, but the performance difference vs `ifelse` is negligible - a tiny bit slower actually. But the code is cleaner.

```
fn.Delay2 <- function(pf.d.day, pf.s.Freq){
    case_when(
        pf.s.Freq == "day"     ~ ceiling_date(pf.d.day + days(1), unit = "day"),
        pf.s.Freq == "week"    ~ ceiling_date(pf.d.day + days(1), unit = "week", week_start = 1),
        pf.s.Freq == "month"   ~ ceiling_date(pf.d.day + days(1), unit = "month"  ),
        pf.s.Freq == "quarter" ~ ceiling_date(pf.d.day + days(1), unit = "quarter"),
        pf.s.Freq == "year"    ~ ceiling_date(pf.d.day + days(1), unit = "year"   ),
        pf.s.Freq != "BiWeek"  ~ as.Date("1900-1-2"), #default date if pf.s.Freq is wrong
        day(pf.d.day) < 15     ~ pf.d.day - day(pf.d.day) + 15,
        TRUE                   ~ ceiling_date(pf.d.day, unit = "month")
    )
}
```

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rowwise = dd %>%rowwise() %>% mutate(Df = fn.Delay(Di, Fr)),
  vectorized = dd %>% mutate(Df = fn.Delay(Di, Fr)),
  case_when = dd %>% mutate(Df = fn.Delay2(Di, Fr))
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
#     rowwise 10.0593 12.47230 13.59725 13.00590 14.1138 30.3810   100
#  vectorized  7.5237  7.97235 10.21504 10.26205 10.7905 25.7858   100
#   case_when  7.7331  8.43595 10.42024 10.54705 11.1035 21.4732   100
```

Comment: thanks! not entirely sure what my bug was because the function clearly wasn't vectorized as i was getting the same date across all rows, but i'm guessing that while cleaning the code for SO i "accidentally" fixed the issue. Thanks very much, it looks like it's 7x faster after removing both the rowwise as well as the ifelse